# WordPress sage template can't loop out acf repeater field

Tags: php, html, wordpress

For some unknown reason I can't loop out a repeater field in my front-page.php. I am using the sage theme as a base.

This is what my base.php looks like:

```
<?php

use Roots\Sage\Setup;
use Roots\Sage\Wrapper;

?>

<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
  <?php get_template_part('templates/head'); ?>
  <body <?php body_class(); ?> style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);">
    <!--[if IE]>
      <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <?php _e('You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.', 'sage'); ?>
      </div>
    <![endif]-->

        <?php include Wrapper\template_path(); ?>

    <?php
      do_action('get_footer');
      get_template_part('templates/footer');
      wp_footer();
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what my front-page.php looks like:

```
<div class="slider-circles">
  <?php if( have_rows('field_56e7d8bebb545') ): ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows('field_56e7d8bebb545') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <p id="slide1" data-bgimage="<?php the_sub_field('field_56e7d8cebb546'); ?>" class="transparent-circle slick-active"></p>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Funny thing is I've done this exact same thing a few days ago on an other project and everything worked fine. I have absolutely no idea why it doesn't work now :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default wordpress loop on front-page.php applies to the post content of the static page assigned to 'Settings > Reading ->Posts page'.

Try dumping the values of the repeater field using

`<?php die(var_dump(get_field('field_56e7d8bebb545'))); ?>`

If you're not seeing any values for the repeater field (and things like the_title() aren't working) then the loop probably isn't executing.

Check that you've set the "Front page displays" to "a static page", as per the instructions here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: I've set them up in my wp-admin. Your code doesn't seem to working either.

Comment: Add: 

    <?php die(var_dump(get_field('field_56e7d8bebb545'))); ?>

Is anything outputted?

Comment: I've tried every possible var_dump and none work not even a simple the_title() dump

Comment: Okay well if the_title() isn't working then you're not in a Wordpress loop. 
Have you set the Static Front Page property, as per instructions here: 

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: Oh wauw I am an idiot I completely forgot this. Thanks a lot friend!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106371/discussion-between-frank-lucas-and-joe-czucha).